# Deleting a package from the packaging org

Tags: managed-package

We have this scenario now: 
We have 2 orgs :
Developer org ( where actually development takes place)
Packaging org ( where the package is created and uploaded)

We had a released version published say 2.0. We took the decision of heavily refactoring the code base of our application. In a new sandbox we then started off with a new database architecture. Now it is very difficult to move the code into the packaging org unless we delete the entire package.

Version 2.0 is installed at one customer's org. So if we decide to delete the package entirely and then move our code from the new sandbox to the packaging site and package again. How do you think this will affect the customer? Do you know of any other issues we might face?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can ask salesforce to revert back changes as it was before but before doing that you must uninstall this package from every client's org where you have installed this package.